# Css background stripes on a div

Tags: css, linear-gradients

How do I make the div with the black outline look have it's background to look like this.
[image]

```
background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #000 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, #000 50%, #000 75%, transparent 75%, #fff);
  background-size: 50px 50px;
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: The gradient in your question is basically there, just a few modifications to the angle and gradient breakpoints and it will match. What are you stuck on?

Answer (score 1):

Your gradient almost gives what you want, but it's a bit fixed i.e. not very responsive to the width.

This snippet uses a simpler gradient - it just has one black and one transparent stripe. This is put as a (repeated) background image to a before pseudo element on the div. This way we can get the border radius set easily.

```css
div {
  width: 350px;/* just for demo */
  aspect-ratio: 20 /1;
  border: solid black 2px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #000 45%, transparent 45%, transparent 50%, #000 50% 100%);
  background-size: 50px 100%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-position: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```